# Clipboard API call throws NotAllowedError without invoking onPermissionRequest()

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, clipboard

I have a simple page with a button, that when pressed, uses the Async Clipboard API to write to the clipboard.

```html
<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="testClipboard();">
    Test Clipboard
  </button>
</body>
```

```js
function testClipboard() {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText("Clipboard API Test").then(
    v => alert("Success"),
    e => alert("Fail\n" + e));
}
```

This works on both Chrome and Firefox, desktop and mobile. However on Android Webview it throws the following error:

`NotAllowError: Write permission denied.`

---

I figured I need to override `WebChromeClient.onPermissionRequest()` to grant the permission, but strangely `onPermissionRequest()` does not seem to have been invoked, and the same error is still thrown.

```java
public class WebChromeController extends WebChromeClient {
  @Override
  public void onPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request) {
    Log.d("myTag", "Permission request");
    Log.d("myTag", request.getResources().toString());
    request.grant(request.getResources());
  }
}
protected void initWebView() {
  // ...
  myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeController());
}
```

I still get the same error:

`NotAllowError: Write permission denied.`

Also Logcat logged nothing.

---

I suspected maybe my Android App requires additional permissions to access the clipboard, but according to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#clipboard-data, my App should have permission when it has focus. Indeed, the following code works:

```java
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("MyLbl", "I have permission");
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

I also declared the following in `AndroidManifest.xml` in case the action of requesting permission requires permission:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
```

This did nothing.

So it is probably not an issue with App level permission.

---

What is happening?

How can I get Async Clipboard API calls to work in Webview?

---

OS: Android 10 Q

Webview: v. 81.0.4044.111

Comment: Similar question, also no answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61429649/copy-to-clipboard-using-navigator-clipboard-writetext-not-working-in-android-web

Comment: I know nothing about Android, but [this article from Google refers to using the Permissions API (of the browser)](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/clipboardapi#security_and_permissions).

Comment: Could be a bug.

Comment: @hereticMonkey thx for the link but I don't think it changes anything. It states "attempting to read or write clipboard data will automatically prompt the user for permission if it hasn't already been granted", implying there is no explicit way to request this permission in JS other than just trying to use the clipboard, which I believe is true. As mentioned in the question, when I do that in a Webview environment, `onPermissionRequest()` has in fact never been invoked.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Clipboard API's `writeText` method docs says, we need to obtain `clipboard-write` permission using Permissions API but `navigator.permission` is undefined in WebView, maybe because they don't want to mix web permissions with Android OS permissions.

There is one more way by which we can copy text to clipboard from Android WebView: by calling native Java method from WebView JavaScript (JS) code.

Enable JS in WebView:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Add JS interface:

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "NativeAndroid");
```

Create a method to copy the text to clipboard using `android.content.ClipboardManager`:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void copyToClipboard(String text) {
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("demo", text);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
}
```

Then call the above method using `testClipboard`:

```
function testClipboard() {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText("Clipboard API Test").then(
    v => alert("Success"),
    e => alert("Fail\n" + e));
    
  NativeAndroid.copyToClipboard("Clipboard API Test");
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised that `Android Webview` didn't implement `navigator.permission`. Well, that's a shame. I'll use your workaround for the time being. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is surprising, because other permissions like camera, microphone are working through `PermissionRequest` inside webview.

Comment: @NihthiyaAlthaf In your webpage html/js file, where you want to copy text to the clipboard.

Comment: @AnkitMakwana i got that copy button from sdk in my webpage

Comment: Clipboard is one of the permissions that are not implemented in Android WebView, see [this line](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/master/android_webview/browser/aw_permission_manager.cc#:~:text=case%20PermissionType::CLIPBOARD_READ_WRITE:) and its surroundings in the Chromium source code for details.

Comment: Can you tell me where to put the @JavascriptInterface part? For me, the text is turning red and I'm getting a build error: MainActivity.java:805: error: cannot find symbol
    [at]JavascriptInterface
     ^
  symbol:   class JavascriptInterface
  location: class MainActivity

Comment: @LaurensSwart 1. Check if minSdkVersion is 17 or above because JavascriptInterface is introduced in JellyBean 2. WebAppInterface class should be inside your Activity where you've kept the webview. 3. Make sure the import statement is there.

Comment: Is there any solution for this only changing client code?

Comment: I have third party webpage and facing same issue can anyone help me if found appropriate solution.

Comment: I have the same problem with a third party webpage, have you managed to find anything @RohitSharma?

Comment: But in JS part, it does not know the "NativeAndroid", what should write inside this function in JS? is it function or interface or what? thanks @AnkitMakwana

Comment: @DavidOli Once you add JS interface to webview object and add some function in the JS interface, you can call that method in javascript using that interface name. In above case, it is 'NativeAndroid', you are free to choose the name for interface. Check this doc for more info: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript

Answer (score 4):

I made a trick based on [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61546346/) and it is a very simple solution

Enable JS in WebView:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
```

Then you need to apply this JavaScript code on every page in WebView , you can use onPageStarted method of WebViewClient

```
myWebView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:navigator.clipboard.writeText = (msg) => { return Android.writeToClipboard(msg); }", null)
```

Add JS interface:

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewInterface(), "Android")
```

Create a method to copy the text to clipboard :

```
class WebViewInterface(private val context: Context) {

@JavascriptInterface
fun writeToClipboard(message: String):Boolean {
        context.copyTextToClipBoard(message)
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, the only missing part is that you need to evaluate that javascript every page change, for example in onPageLoaded method of WebViewClient

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my solution will help someone. I warn you, this is bad solution:) But only working in my case

The point is that when copying with `navigator.clipboard.writeText()` inside WebView, a DOMException occurs, which calls the onConsoleMessage method of WebChromeClient.

**Suitable for those who do not have access to js code.**

```
webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onConsoleMessage(
                message: String?,
                lineNumber: Int,
                sourceID: String?
            ) {
                if(url?.contains("https://some-link.com") == true // the page where the copying takes place
                    && message?.contains("object DOMException") == true) { // navigator.clipboard.writeText() causes this exception
                    evaluateJavascript(
                        "document.getElementById('text_to_be_copied').innerText"
                    ) { text ->
                            val myClipboard: ClipboardManager = getSystemService(requireContext(), ClipboardManager::class.java) as ClipboardManager
                            val clip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text)
                            myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip)
                    }
                }
                super.onConsoleMessage(message, lineNumber, sourceID)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to
https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/blob/main/packages/core/useClipboard/index.ts
If page is embedded in Android WebView, use **legacyCopy** instead of Clipboard API

```
function legacyCopy(value: string) {
    const ta = document.createElement('textarea')
    ta.value = value ?? ''
    ta.style.position = 'absolute'
    ta.style.opacity = '0'
    document.body.appendChild(ta)
    ta.select()
    document.execCommand('copy')
    ta.remove()
}
```