# clipboard readtext not working in android webview

Tags: android, clipboard

Inside our android webview app, we are trying to paste the copied content from another app eg (notes) using navigator.clibpboard.readtext function. It works just fine in mobile chrome, but in android webview, which is again based on chromium engine, it just does not work.

We have given all permission in android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CLIPBOARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CLIPBOARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.webkit.PermissionRequest" />
```

Stackoverflow has couple of threads on how to copy text clipboard inside android webview, but not on pasting the text from navigator.clipboard, so that's why had to raise this issue.
Any ideas on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced such problem. It only takes four simple steps to implement this feature. The solution that worked for me is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61546346/19261915

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).