# android WebView: copy to clipboard [https://poe.com]

Tags: android, webview, copy, clipboard, clipboard.js

'So I converted [https://poe.com] into android app.but when I copy text inside the app I get error message [clipboard error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf9jF.jpg) .'

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://poe.com/");
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
    }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.isFocused() && webView.canGoBack())
    {
        webView.goBack();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

}

---

Answer (score 0):

"Copy to Clipboard" not working on android web view. There is a solution, but it is a little troublesome, you can apply it.
[You can check the possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61546346/10187218)